# Application downloading error (919)

Tags: google-play-store, 4.1-jelly-bean

I am experiencing a problem with Google Play in my Android phone.
When I download new apps from the Play Store, it completes 100% and then shows me an error:

`(unknown Error code during application install:''919'')`

Comment: Could be an issue with your network, if we believe SO: [unknown error code during application install 919](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19652367/2533433)

Comment: this happened with me the other day and i believe as izzy said it has to do with the network.

Comment: I get this error installing some apps, but for others it works just fine.... What is the issue? I don't understand...

Answer (score 8):

<sup>Converted from my comment on the question itself:</sup>

According to a [post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19652367/2533433), this is most likely a network issue. In his answer there, [Vignesh writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19653935):

> Its due to wifi restriction, when i connect the internet through my service provider its working fine. Able to install any application.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same thing when updating apps. Tried over wifi and service provider network same thing was not with just one app all apps that were set to up date even google apps.  I cleared the cache and it seems to be working fine now settings/app manager/googleplaystore/clear cache

Comment: An anonymous user inserted the following as an edit "It has to do with insufficient storage. Clearing the cache will free up a little space, but you will need to remove or export old unused apps/media."

Answer (score 1):

I Know its already answered but this answer may help to fix it and help someone. [source link](http://appslova.com/android-fix-error-919-app-installation/)

**Method 1**

Check your phone memory, how much is free. You can transfer your apps to sd card through ‘apps2sd/app manager’ (free). Clear your cache and data now. For this, follow these steps:

1. Go to menu>settings
2. Go to Application and then press manage application.
3. Now select google play.
4. Then you have to click on clear cache.
5. After that come to the home screen.
6. Go to `download manager`.
7. Select **clear data.**
8. Once you clear the data the problem will resolved.

**Method 2**

If your problem isn’t solved by using **method 1**, try using a different internet connection than you’ve used previously. It means, if you are using your mobile data to download and install or update the apps, you can try using your wi-fi network, or vice-versa. This method is reported to work in most of the devices by the users.

**Method 3**

Change your APN (access point name) settings:

1. Go to menu > settings > wireless and networks > mobile networks > access point names.
2. Edit APN settings as one of your friend’s APN in the same carrier.

The **method 1** is the most commonly used, and you can try it first and in case it doesn’t work, you can try those which are given underneath.