# Error code 919 when updating or installing apps

Tags: applications, updates

I am on holiday using hotel Wi-Fi.  None of my apps will update, and I cannot install any new ones. Got the mesage error code 919. Is it the hotel Wi-Fi or a tablet problem (Sony S)?

Comment: My first guess would be that some protocol required by the Play Store is blocked by the hotel.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Actually, your question has already been asked and is waiting for an answer here: [application downloading error (919)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56258/16575), so you might wish to watch out for answers there.