# Why can't I install apps after a factory reset?

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-3

I factory restored my samsung galaxy S3 its not letting me update or download and apps on google play when I do try at the end it says unknown error install of191 I believe that what it says can someone tell me what I should do

Comment: Are you sure the error number isn't 919?

Comment: What Dan refers to: [Application downloading error (919)](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/56258/16575). Links for other playstore errors can be found in our [google-play-store tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/google-play-store/info) (in the "troubleshooting" section).